# C - Linux - Pthreads and Semaphore

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I am having trouble trying to implement semaphores with pthreads. The scenario that I am trying to program are rats in a maze. Where rats are threads and the maze consists of rooms connected to each other. The rats have to traverse through each room with each room having a different capacity and wait time before a rat can move on. I was able to implement it with a while loop and let the threads sit and spin while waiting for a spot to free up but I need to achieve the objective with semaphores. Here's what I have:

```
sem_t psem, csem;

void EnterRoom(int iRat, int iRoom) {

    time_t currentTime;

    currentTime = time(NULL);

    RoomVB[iRoom][iRat].tEntry = currentTime - startTime;
    RoomVB[iRoom][iRat].iRat = iRat;
    VisitorCount[iRoom]++;
    sleep(roomArray[iRoom].delay);
}

void LeaveRoom(int iRat, int iRoom) {

    time_t currentTime;

    currentTime = time(NULL);

    VisitorCount[iRoom]--;
    RoomVB[iRoom][iRat].tDep = currentTime - startTime;
}

void *rat(void *ratID) {

    if (sem_init(&csem, 0, 0) < 0) {
        perror("sem_init");
        exit(1);
    }

    int id;

    id = (int)ratID;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numOfRooms; i++) {

    /*while (VisitorCount[i] >= roomArray[i].capacity) {

    }*/

    if (sem_init(&psem, 0, roomArray[i].capacity) < 0) {
        perror("sem_init");
        exit(1);
        }


    sem_wait(&psem);
    EnterRoom(id, i);
    sem_post(&csem);

    sem_wait(&csem);
    LeaveRoom(id, i);
    sem_post(&psem);

    }

    return NULL;

}
```

As you can see I commented out the while loop. I had to incorporate additional information like the time it it takes for a rat to travel through rooms in a 2D array.

Error result:

```
Rat 0 completed maze in 5 seconds.
Rat 1 completed maze in 5 seconds.
Rat 2 completed maze in 5 seconds.
Room 0 [3 1]: 0 0 1; 1 0 1; 2 0 1; 
Room 1 [2 2]: 0 1 3; 1 1 3; 2 1 3; 
Room 2 [1 2]: 0 3 5; 1 3 5; 2 3 5; 
Total traversal time: 15 seconds, compared to ideal time: 15 seconds.
```

Correct result (achieved with loop):

```
Rat 0 completed maze in 7 seconds.
Rat 1 completed maze in 5 seconds.
Rat 2 completed maze in 9 seconds.
Room 0 [3 1]: 0 0 1; 1 0 1; 2 0 1; 
Room 1 [2 2]: 0 1 3; 1 1 3; 2 3 5; 
Room 2 [1 2]: 0 5 7; 1 3 5; 2 7 9; 
Total traversal time: 21 seconds, compared to ideal time: 15 seconds.
```

I assume I need two semaphores with the producer semaphore being initially set to n - which is the capacity of each room. Any ideas how I fix it so it works as it should?

Comment: Please describe what the actual problem is. That is, how the program is not behaving as expected. And ideally should provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. I'm guessing you have been staring at this for a long time so understand the output well. But to help others it would be good to highlight what is wrong with the actual output. Is it just the traversal time? Is it the order of traversal? etc. I'm sure people could work it out by reading through your code carefully. But the easier you make it to understand the more likely you will get an answer.

Comment: Don't you need a sempahore for each room rather than a `VisitorCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have each thread re-initialise the same two shared semaphores simultaneously.  The semaphores all need to be initialised up-front, before your rats start running.

The easiest way to solve this will be to have one semaphore for each room, initialised to the capacity of that room (store the sempahore in the `roomArray` element for that room).  Then, just have the rat wait on the semaphore when it enters the room, and post the semaphore when it exits the room.

Comment: oh haha so basically replace VisitorCount[] with array of semaphores?

Comment: Pretty much.  But when entering the room you want to wait on the semaphore *before* getting the current time, since you haven't actually entered the room until the semaphore returns (when leaving the room you still post the semaphore after getting the time though).  And you'll need to run a loop to initialise those semaphores before starting the rats.